# How to handle optional parameters in powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, parameters, dynamic-programming, optional-parameters

Question:

I am writing a cmdlet that will accept parameters and send emails. "Cc" is one of the parameters; and is non-mandatory. 
 Today the code shows TWO lines invoking Send-MailMessage (like the following paragraph), but i am sure there is a better way to write it:

```
if( $cc -eq $null){  
    Send-MailMessage -From $from ...    ## call without -Cc  
} else {  
    Send-MailMessage -From $from ... -Cc $cc...     ## call WITH -Cc  
}
```

I would like to avoid *branching* and writing the  line twice.

Or even worse than "twice", writing all the combinations for each optional parameter.

(Of course, the fact that the cmdlet sends email is not important here. The problem will stand for any cmdlet that needs to avoid optional parameters)

What is the best-practice way to do this?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

Use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj672955.aspx):

```
$Params = @{}
if($ShouldUseCc) {
    $Params.Add('Cc', $CcValue)
}
if($ShouldUseBcc) {
    $Params.Add('Bcc', $BccValue)
}
Send-MailMessage -From $from ... @Params
```